# Converting Keras Model to TF Lite

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have a Keras model already saved as an .h5 file. How do I convert this to a TensorFlow Lite file?

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjmE2.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rfzz.png)

I keep seeing this line in tutorials `converter.convert()`
but it just gives me this error 
`KeyError: 'kernel'`

Comment: Could be an issue with Google Colab/Jupyter, whichever you are using

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've figured out the problem. The issue lies in the fact that I was using LSTM layers in my model. This is a known bug the developers acknowledged[image: Here].

When changing my model to only dense layers the conversion worked fine. I hope this saves people hours of painstaking research.